# how to display/report back progress of Task(Async) actions?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have the need to move some processes to async.  I have 5 methods that I need to call individually and have run in the background so the user can continue on with their work.

The test code below seems to work... but I haven't been able to figure out how to return information (message) indicating that the a task has completed.  The class will be called from a separate windows form so that the progress can be displayed....

from the form:

```
    async void BtnGo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = @"Starting tasks...";
        var progress = new Progress<string>(
            p =>
            {
                label2.Text = p;
            });
        await TestTask.MyTestMain(progress);
    }
```

the class:

```
public static  class TestTask
{
    public static Task MyTestMain(IProgress<string> pProgress)
    {
        return SomethingAsync(pProgress);
    }

    private static async Task SomethingAsync(IProgress<string> pProgress)
    {
        var t1 = SomeThing1(pProgress);
        var t2 = SomeThing2(pProgress);

        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

        if (pProgress != null) pProgress.Report(@"all tasks completed");
    }

    private static async Task SomeThing1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(9000);

        var filename = @"c:\temp\tt1.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filename))
            File.Delete(filename);

        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            await tw.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        }
        if (pProgress != null) pProgress.Report(@"t1 completed");
    }

    private static async Task SomeThing2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(7000);

        var filename = @"c:\temp\tt2.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filename))
            File.Delete(filename);

        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            await tw.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        }
        if (pProgress != null) pProgress.Report(@"t2 completed");
    }
}
```

I would like know when each task has completed.  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

*EDIT*
I have edited this post to reflect my changes... I still cannot get a progress report back to the UI... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing IO bound work, you don't need to use thread-pool threads.

Transform your methods to use the async APIs of `StreamWriter`:

```
private static async Task FirstThingAsync()
{
    var filename = @"c:\temp\tt1.txt";

    if (File.Exists(filename))
        File.Delete(filename);

    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
       await tw.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Same for your second method, and then you can asynchronously wait on them concurrently:

```
private static async Task SomethingAsync()
{
    var firstThing = FirstThingAsync();
    var secondThing = SecondThingAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(firstThing, secondThing);
}
```

**Edit:**

You're never reaching your first `Progress.Report` call because your code is throwing an `InvalidOperationException` when you call `t.Start()` on a promise-style task:

```
t1.Start();
await t1;

t2.Start();
await t2;
```

The task returned from both method calls is a "hot task", meaning it's operation is already started. The docs on [`Task.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682(v=vs.110).aspx) say:

> **InvalidOperationException**: The Task is not in a valid state to be
>   started. **It may have already been started, executed, or canceled,** or
>   it may have been created in a manner that doesn't support direct
>   scheduling.

The reason you're not seeing that exception is because you're swallowing it:

```
var t = SomethingAsync(pProgress);
```

When you don't await on the async operation. Your method calls should look like this:

```
public static Task MyTestMain(IProgress<string> pProgress)
{
    return SomethingAsync(pProgress);
}

async void BtnGo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = @"Starting tasks...";
    var progress = new Progress<string>(
        p =>
        {
            label2.Text = p;
        });
    await TestTask.MyTestMain(progress);
}
```

Comment: but how do I report back the progress of each task?  I want to know when each task has completed.  This is in a class and I need some way to report back to the form and update the UI with the status of each task.

Comment: Progress is different then completion. If you need progress, look into [`IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want to know about each tasks completion, you can await on them separately instead of with `WhenAll`.

Comment: I just want to know when they complete... So I will need to create an event for the class and fire the event after each await... is that correct?

Comment: You don't need to use an event. `Progress<T>` has a callback that it invokes, where you register a delegate (via the constructor). `Progress<T>.OnReport(T value)`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `Progress` Also has an event that you can subscribe to, instead of, or in addition to, the delegate in the constructor (that's optional).

Comment: Yes, I saw. I should of mentioned it was a personal preference.

Comment: @Kix This solution wasn't what you were looking for?

Comment: Looking at the new code I posted in my question... I still don't get back any progress.  The solution is almost there but I am having trouble getting this last little piece.  I put a break point on the "if (pProgress != null)" statement but when I run the breakpoint never gets hit.  My label never gets updated that I defined in the delegate from the calling UI.

Comment: I noticed the edits and made the changes... however label2 still never gets updated...

Comment: Yeppers.... I changed my SomethingAsync method, see edit on my question... I changed the to also pass in pProgress to my tasks(t2 and t2)  so it does now seem to work... not sure if it was what you had in mind, but ,,,,

Comment: @Kix Does the breakpoint hit now? Seems to work? I don't see an edit. `TestTask` still looks the same

Comment: It seems to work now.... I had to pass in the pProgress  object to the tasks to be handled at each task.  thanks!!!